# wpf datagrid template column export to excel

Tags: c#, wpf, excel, datagrid

Hi I have a wpf datagrid and i tried to export the contents of this datagrid to excel using this method - https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/072555b3-fc32-4a32-b7b5-076b1fe978da/wpf-datagrid-to-excel-export
But the contents of datagrid template column are not exported to the excel sheet. Only the contents of datagrid text column are exported. How to export the contents of datagrid template column. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Templates being virtually anything, there no way to do this. The best you could get is to write some "Template To Text" method before streaming to CSV.